# How to remove left indent in input[type=date] in Chrome (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, css, google-chrome, input

Input with date type in Chrome in iOS and Android has left indent that i can't remove.

Android 4.4.4, iOS 7, Google Chrome

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="Text input">
<br>
<input type="date" value="2014-02-01">
```

CSS

```
input {
    border: 0;
    background: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/pv317knh/

Comment: try `-webkit-appearance:none` to ur inputs

Comment: @VivekVikranth tried, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

UserAgent stylesheet for Chrome/Android has the following:

```
input[type="date" i],
input[type="datetime-local" i],
input[type="month" i],
input[type="time" i],
input[type="week" i] {
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10em;
}
```

It's a flexbox.  So, please try `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: unfortunately, no effect